# Destroy previously calling APIs on button click in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a search button in my project upon clicking it, an API is called. If I click the button again the previously called API will be destroyed and only the newly called API will exist. How can I do this in typescript? I am calling ngDestroy() while I click the button. However, it seems it is not working.

Comment: Why is it not working? Add more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngOnDestroy` is called by *Angular* when a component is destroyed (due to changing route, `ngIf` condition, etc.). You should **never** call it yourself.

You just need to cancel the previous API call; which RxJS does quite well with the `switchMap` operator. This operator will cancel any previous observable when a new emission is given to it. Since you're triggering off a button click, you'll just need to setup a subject:

```js
private submitSource: Subject<void> = new Subject();

public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.submitSource.pipe(
     switchMap(() => this.someService.someApiCall()
   ).subscribe(result => {
    // Use the API call result
   });
}

public buttonClick(): void {
   this.submitSource.next(null);
}
```